# Android 3rd Party Library Integration

Tags: java, android, github, integration

this is kinda crazy. I already worked often with 3rd party librarys. All I had to do was adding the compile command in the build gradle but in this case its something different. This is the github link of the lib i want to implement:

[Link to github](https://github.com/h6ah4i/android-advancedrecyclerview)

I tried to integrate the files I need manually but i got a amount of errors.
In the README the developer says:

*This library is provided as the AAR format. The source jar file won't be downloaded automatically (due to the current Gradle and Android Studio limitation), so javadoc comments are not displayed on IDE.*

Can somebody help me how to integrate this the best way.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a look below, they have already provided a workaround

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://raw.github.com/xujiaao/mvn-repository/master/releases' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.github.xujiaao:aarLinkSources:1.0.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'aar-link-sources'

android {
    ...
}

dependencies {
    compile ('com.h6ah4i.android.widget.advrecyclerview:advrecyclerview:0.8.0@aar'){
        transitive=true
    }
    aarLinkSources 'com.h6ah4i.android.widget.advrecyclerview:advrecyclerview:0.8.0:sources@jar'
}
```

Comment: I have no access to the lib in Android Studio: Cannot resolve symbol "nameofaclass"